# editing non-master branch in git

Tags: git

I created new branch and checkouted to it

```
git branch new_branch
git checkout new_branch
```

and edited some file in it

```
vim main.cpp
do_something
```

`git status` shows that main.cpp was changed. Now I going back to master branch

```
git checkout master
```

and this changes are in master, too, despite I've changed file in `new_brach`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your changes are nowhere, they are still only modified files not yet committed, you can safely switch to `new_branch` again, you need to be on `new_branch` and `commit` to add your changes there. Once you have committed on new_branch and switch branch master will be clean. If you want to get your commit in master you can either merge both branches os cherry-pick the single commit.

Answer (score 1):

Did you commit your changes?

Your order of events should be:

1. Switch to branch
2. Make your changes
3. Commit your changes
4. Switch to your original branch.

Unless you commit, git will not leave your changes behind when you switch branches, since as far as git is concerned, they never happened. Committing in git tells git to record your changes on the branch you're currently on.

Comment: no, I didnt. Does it mean that changes would be applyed to master branch?

Comment: No it doesn't. Changes are committed to the branch you're on only (though you can later merge or cherry-pick them over if you want to).

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anything wrong,please check it again 
and try

```
$ git checkout -b iss53
```

To create a branch and switch to it at the same time, you can run the git checkout command with the -b switch